# Package dependencies cannot be resolved

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Package dependencies cannot be resolved:

When I try to install full ros desktop package in Ubuntu 11.04, I get the error above. When I tried to use terminal window installation, it states that a lot of dependencies are missing such as tutorials and slam g-mapping and gives broken package error in the end.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9904/package-dependencies-cannot-be-resolved/) by [gokmev](https://answers.ros.org/users/500/gokmev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Support for 11.04 is still under development. Posting the full output of the error message might help get this resolved -- providing a patch to the developers will certainly resolve it even faster.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1